# Why does `jQuery` `hide()` method not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've done this before and yet I'm stuck in this simple implementation.

Here's the html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id='hiding'>blah</p>
    <p>blahblah</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

The `hide()` doesn't work, and passing in the `hiding` id also doesn't work.

Comment: Check your developer tools console for any meaningful error messages that may indicate what the problem is

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nyqhdkpz/ created jsfiddle working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the order of script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I neglected to check the order of the imports.

Answer (score 1):

Use .on, because it's allows for dynamically created Dom objects to be manipulated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("p").on('click', function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

});

that should to the job. :)

Answer (score 1):

check this and arrange scripts file also

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s8191o77/